# How to diagnose a vacuum hose leak or pcv pump problem

Tags: mitsubishi, pcv-valve

I have a old 1993 Mitsubishi Triton MJ which is having a bit of an issue at the moment with acceleration. With the initial acceleration such as moving away from traffic lights the engine will often sputter and struggle and almost stall.

From my basic knowledge and knowing the fuel lines and filter aren't blocked I have come to the conclusion that it is a vacuum leak or issue with the pcv pump.

Is there any way to diagnose which it is before replacing parts?

Having said that, it's probably worth going through and replacing all the vacuum hoses anyway on a vehicle of this age.

Comment: Is there actually a PCV valve on the Mitsubishi Triton. I have the same vehicle though it's a 1994 version. If there is one where is the PCV valve on the is vehicle?

Answer (score 2):

For such a cheap part, if you suspect the vacuum hoses then just replace it to remove it from the list of possible causes.

From my knowledge the MJ tritons were still carburettor. If this is the case then perhaps it might be worth trying to diagnose a possible carburettor issue. If it performs this behaviour at any particular throttle position then it might be easier to diagnose as a carb issue. i.e. if it does it constantly when getting towards WOT then you might find it's a blocked, dirty or clogged main jet, if it's always in the middle range then it could be jet needle etc

Best of luck with it.